# Conditional order_by depending on data in Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am wondering if there is a way to sort using some kind of `if/then` semantics for the sort order.

The basic requirement I am trying to adress is this:

- My records have a contact_again_time time attribute that can be `nil`.
- The list should be sorted in a way that all records that do have a `contact_again_time` come first ordered by `contact_again_time` descending.
- The rest where `contact_again_time` is nil should be ordered by created_at in ascending.

So off the top of my head I could solve this by materializing the order field into the index by having my `searchable` look like this:

```
integer :sort_key do                                                                                                                                             
  contact_again_time.nil? ? (created_at.to_i * -1) : contact_again_time.to_i                                                                                     
end
```

And then do a `order_by(:sort_key, :desc)` to get what I want. 
But this way I am putting part of the sort logic inside my model and more importantly inside the Lucene Index.

Something I'd rather avoid as it feels rather wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solr, you can do this by adding `sort` parameter to your query:
`sort=contact_again_time desc,created_at asc`

Whenever `contact_again_time` is present, it would sort in descending order (and use `created_at` to break ties, which is irrelevant to you). When only `created_at` is present those will be sorted in ascending order.

This should translate in a straight-forward manner to sunspot.

**Update**: If you want to sort like `sort=contact_again_time asc,created_at asc` you will get the documents where `contact_again_time` is missing first, like you mention in your comment below. To push these documents to the end, add `sortMissingLast="true"` to `contact_again_time` in your Solr schema.xml. If `created_at` can also be absent in some documents and you desire the same behavior, you should add `sortMissingLast` to it too.

Comment: I would say that is almost exactly the answer I was looking for. Only problem I just ran into is that I now need to sort the first field ascending, so nil values are sorted ahead in that case which defeats the purpose of :(